# How to Achieve Efficient Range Query over Encrypted Data in Cloud

Tags: java, cloud

i want to achieve efficient range query over an encrypted data in cloud computing.
it is still challenging to efficiently process encrypted data in semi-trust cloud server.
Algorithm

```
Input: processing key gpt, encrypted key [xi] = Cxi and case-1:
[a] = Ca; [y] = Cy or case-2: [b] = Cb; [y] = Cy
Output: 1 (result is >=) or 0 (result is <)
1 compute Cx = Cxi  Cy = gs(xi+y)  hry+ri
2 if case-1: [a]; [y] then
3 compute Xi = e(Ca
Cx
; gpt) = e(g; g)pst(s+a(xi+y))
4 compute the hash value H(Xi)
5 if H(Xi) in the set H then
6 return 0 // showing a < (xi + y)
7 else
8 return 1 // showing a  (xi + y)
9 else if case-2: [b]; [y] then
10 compute Xi = e( Cb
Cx
; gpt) = e(g; g)pst(s+b(xi+y))
11 compute the hash value H(Xi)
12 if H(Xi) in the set H then
13 return 0 // showing b < (xi + y)
14 else
15 return 1 // showing b  (xi + y)
```